# Vimrc: combine commands with fugitive

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I'm trying to combine

```
:w
:Gcommit -a -m "update"
:Gpush
```

to a new Command like :W – I've tried

```
:command! W w | Gcommit -a -m "update" | Gpush
```

But it doesn't work because he treats Gpush as a shell-command instead of a vim-command.

Comment: Do not use "update" as all your commit messages. [Commit messages](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) should [mean something](http://mislav.net/2014/02/hidden-documentation/)

Comment: Well I just use this for one of my gitrepos where I don't need any commit-message because I only use git for syncing my todo-list across platforms (and keep a history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:command! W w | execute "Gcommit -a -m 'update'" | Gpush
```

`Gcommit` has not been given `-bar` argument that would allow it to terminate at the bar (and prohibit it from taking the bar as an argument). Thus, use `execute` to isolate the command, as described in `:help :|`. See also `:help :command-bar`.